# Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c-blocks

Given the following:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60
                                                           target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(doSomething)
                                                         userInfo: nil
                                                          repeats: NO];
    });
}
```

Where myTimer is declared in a private interface:

```
@interface MyClass()
{
    NSTimer * myTimer;
}
@end
```

How would one fix the following warning:

```
Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior
```

From what I have found so far, most suggestions involve putting something such as:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
    __typeof__(self) __weak wself = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        wself.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60
                                                           target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(doSomething)
                                                         userInfo: nil
                                                          repeats: NO];
    });
}
```

Except, that myTimer is an ivar, meaning `wself` does not have access to any properties.

I guess my questions are:

1. Do/should I care?
2. Should I declare myTimer as a property?

I use ivars quite a bit through my code. I just added the `-Weverything` flag to my project to see if I can find any underlying issues and this is by far the most common warning. I have no problem going though and fixing it by making my ivars properties, but I want to make sure I get a better understanding before I do that.

Comment: "Except, that wself is an ivar, meaning wself does not have access to any properties." - wat?

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry, that should have said 'except that myTimer is an ivar'.

Comment: I've started getting this warning after upgrading to Xcode 9.3 today, and following Xcode's own recommendation to update project settings. All out of nothing, I've got 300+ warning messages on the project.

Comment: Is this a Swift induced warning? If so, why are still objected to memory management intricacies while we should be writing code.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Replacing `myTimer` by `self->myTimer` would fix your warning.

When you use an iVar `_iVar` in the code, the compiler will replace the code by `self->_iVar`, and if you use it inside a block, the block will capture self instead of the iVar itself. The warning is just to make sure that the developer understand this behaviour.

Comment: I am also getting this error, but I have a confusion will it cause any memory leak????

Comment: @Surbhi Garg On the contrary, a `weak` pointer means the retain count does not change. The only issue is that `self` *will* get released before it's used.

Comment: One thing though, as I understand, allocating a `dispatch_async` inside a method (rather then holding it strongly) will not create a retain cycle anyway. The block may retain `self`, but `self` does not retain the block. So I take it that these warning simply air on adopting 'good habits'?

Comment: Came across this warning recently and I was wondering if there's a better solution that doesn't require me to put `self->` in front of each `_iVar` in my code: there are plenty in my block and it would be visually very messy.

Comment: @Andrea, some solutions, if you are just reading the `iVar`, you can just create a local variable before the block which contains the iVar value and use it

Comment: You can also move all the block logic inside a method and call it inside the block.

Comment: Thanks @bsarr007! Went for the second option... have multiple `iVars` and didn't want to create a bunch of local variables...

Answer (score 75):

### Details

Xcode: 9.2, 10.2, 11.0 (11A420a)

### Warnings in Objective-C Pods

I have swift project. Warning `Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior` appears when I use Objective-C pods:

- Bolts
- FBSDKCoreKit
- FBSDKLoginKit

[image]

### Solution 1 (manual)

```
CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF = NO
```

### Solution 2 (automatic)

> Add to the end of your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
           target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF'] = 'NO'
           end
      end
 end
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: Thx @Vasily Bodnarchuk, was able to solve the error in Xcode 9.2. Are there any other implication by changing the flag to no?

Comment: I changed this flag in three Swift projects. I have no errors.

Comment: @user1872384 Turning this flag on or off has zero affect on how your code compiles or how it operates. You'll just no longer receive this very useful warning where you have implicit references to `self` that might otherwise escape your attention. If you're stuck with third party library where you're getting tons of these warnings, I can understand wanting to turn this off. But I'd suggest keeping this warning turned on for your own code, and just replace implicit references to `self` with explicit ones, and making sure there are no strong reference cycles in those cases.

Answer (score 15):

For those of you getting these warnings because of `Bolts`/`FBSDKCoreKit`/`FBSDKLoginKit`, you should avoid Vasily's answer and instead silence the warnings for those specific dependencies.

### Option 1

Mention each pods instead of just FacebookCore and add `inhibit_warnings: true`

```
pod 'FacebookCore', inhibit_warnings: true
pod 'Bolts', inhibit_warnings: true
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', inhibit_warnings: true
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', inhibit_warnings: true
```

### Option 2

Or silence all pods, by adding to your Podfile this:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

### Conclusion

You'll still get warnings for your own code. Not getting those could be problematic at some point, that's why I believe it's a better solution.

Next time you update the Facebook sdk, see if you can remove the `inhibit_warnings: true` or `inhibit_all_warnings!`.

Comment: I don't see a problem in Vasily's answer. It applies only to Pods project, but not your whole project.

Comment: @Starsky it's an issue because it applies to all Pods, so it will hide warnings of other Pods

Answer (score 5):

This fixes my problem for Xcode 9.3

```
- (void) someMethod{

    __weak MyClass *wSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    MyClass *sSelf = wSelf;
    if(sSelf != nil){
        wself.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60
                                                       target: self
                                                     selector:@selector(doSomething)
                                                     userInfo: nil
                                                      repeats: NO];
       }

   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I faced the same issue and @Vasily Bodnarchuk answer seems to be helpful.

However in Continuous integration environments its not possible to change the `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF` flag to `NO` at run time.
So in order to isolate the issue i tried by checking all the dependent GEMS installed by Cocoapods and figured out that gem XCODEPROJ version 1.5.7 sets the `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF` to `YES` whenever `pod install` command is executed. 
The solution for this is reverting the *XCODEPROJ* to earlier version 1.5.1 by executing `sudo gem install xcodeproj -v 1.5.1`
Once reverted just execute `pod install` and the flag will be set to NO always.

Comment: It worked for me !!!. The answer should be accepted as correct. It saved my day. Thanks @bhuvan

Comment: @PallavTrivedi - I do not think this should be the accepted answer. Don't get me wrong, this answer is correct insofar as it successfully silences the warning. But this warning is extremely useful. I would suggest making your `self` references explicit (where you can glance at your code and easily see candidates for strong reference cycle problems) rather than have not-so-obvious implicit reference to `self` escape one's attention. Apple added this useful warning for a reason.

Comment: I agree, I was just downvoted for answering the same way. Do not silence the warning by removing it. Silence the warning by not incorrectly referencing self. It can create retain cycles.