# How to fix multiple similar warnings in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After updating to XCode 9.3 I have 1167 warnings saying:

`Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior`

Is there a way to fix all of them at once? Or if not, is there a way **press a keyboard button to activate `Fix` button** on that warning?

Comment: Not saying this is a good idea but you can turn off the warning. In the Build Settings for your target, find the "Implicit retain of 'self' within blocks" warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577711/block-implicitly-retains-self-explicitly-mention-self-to-indicate-this-is-i)

Comment: I'm backed off to my original question. Multiple fixing is what I'm trying to figure out. The question you mention says nothing about that.

Comment: Sadly, I don't believe there is an automated solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF = NO
```

[image]

[Full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028910/4488252)