# Swift-Firebase iOS SDK showing GTMSessionFetcher warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, gtmsessionfetcher

I am using Xcode 9.3(iOS deployment target 11.3) and installed the Firebase iOS SDK following this setup guide: [Firebase iOS setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Everything went well except that I am getting a lot of GTMSessionFetcher warning when I build the app. Like the image below.
[GTMSessionFetcher warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxhD8.png)

I did nothing but following the setup guide. Anyone know how to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: This is a warning only and will not effect  your code. The warning is just to make sure the developer understand this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577711/block-implicitly-retains-self-explicitly-mention-self-to-indicate-this-is-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clean your project(Derived Data), and update or reinstall your Pod files.

Comment: Updated the pod files and the warnings went away thanks!

Comment: Any time, if you can give me a thumb up.